# Cannot play video stream from FFMPEG to VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, udp, h.264

I'm trying to stream my local webcam using FFMPEG. For test purposes, I'm doing this locally and try to open the stream using VLC (3.0.8, Windows 10). This is how I stream from FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Microsoft Camera Front" -preset fast -s 1280x720
       -vcodec libx264 -tune ssim -b 500k -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

I can play the stream seamlessly using

```
ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

However, I cannot get this working using VLC. I click "Open network stream" and tried different formats, like `udp://127.0.0.1:1234` or `udp://@:127.0.0.1:1234` or `udp://@:1234`. Using the latter, it manages to open the stream, but it does not show any video. However, from the codec information window, it even seems to detect the correct codec (Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264). From the statistics window, I notice that it receives data with a bit rate varing between 40kb/s and 100kb/s, which seems plausible given that I strem with ~560kbit/s.

So it seems to just not show the video. The same happens on another PC with Windows 10. Any ideas what's going wrong? Thank you in advance for any hints!

Comment: Start playback before ffmpeg and check.

Comment: Same result (unfortunately)..

Comment: If you have found a solution please post it.

Answer (score 3):

Add a packet size on both server (ffmpeg) and client (vlc) sides;

in ffmpeg:

```
>ffmpeg -re -i "path/to/my/video.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

in vlc:

```
>udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

Answer (score 1):

in VLC need the symbol "@" to this work

> udp://@127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).