# ffmpeg - Jitter when streaming audio over RTP

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, wireshark

So as a disclaimer, i'm trying to do something with ffmpeg that may be at the limit of what can be achieved. However, even though it's not possible, i would like to understand why.

What I want to do is simply to stream PCM Audio (16bit, mono, 48Khz) over RTP with 4ms audio frame (so basically, 192 samples per frame), with the smallest jitter possible.

This is the configuration i'm currently working with:

```
ffmpeg \
    -re \
    -i ../input.mov \
    -acodec pcm_s16le \
    -vn \
    -ac 1 \
    -af "aresample=48000,asetnsamples=n=192:p=0" \
    -f rtp \
    -payload_type 119 \
    "rtp://127.0.0.1:3333"
```

At first glance the result is pretty convincing, I get 428 packets, each carrying 192 Mono samples, great.

But using Wireshark, I found out that my average jitter is around 7ms. More interestingly, I see that this jitter is mainly cause by 1 every 6 packets that shows *high* reception delay:

[image]

I don't have an advanced undestanding of ffmpeg internals, but I guess this could be the time taken by the RTP muxer to load the next batch of AVPackets? I've noted that increasing the *n* value in asetnsamples would increase the number of packets with acceptable delay, but would increase the delay for the bad one.

Does anyone have an actual explaination for this behavior? Is there any other way for me to optimize my jitter?

Thanks!

Comment: For UDP I saw the [syntax](https://superuser.com/a/1604151/635712) `udp://127.0.0.1:3333?pkt_size=1316` and also `pkt_size=188&buffer_size=65535` (try smaller buffer size). You may also try adding [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50576757/4926757) `-blocksize 2048 -flush_packets 1`, but maybe it's relevant only for files.